# Using Angular 2 and Typescript to build a Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, angular

Currently, I'm trying to build a Chrome App based off the Angular 2 5 minute quick start to build an example Chrome application. However because of how system JS works there are security issues with chrome applications.

does anyone have any experience or pointers with this

https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Comment: you want to develop chrome extension using angular2 ?

Answer (score 1):

They seem to use `eval` which currently prevents Angulars use in Chrome applications. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5956#issuecomment-181565444

> Right now we use eval to get an easier JS interop. But we should revisit this.

Comment: Thank you for link, any ideas on a work around? maybe using something like webpack instead?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I haven't tried to build a Chrome app with Angular2 yet.